# htaccess rewrite trouble with "fake" folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

Before I ask my question, let me start off by saying that I have a working htaccess rule that is:

```
#1.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /folder1/
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*) /good/$1 [L,R=301]
```

and, like I said, this works well.

But, when I try to do this:

```
#2.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /folder1/
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*) /funfolder/good/$1 [L,R=301]
```

this doesn't work anymore.

So here comes my question.

If I want to rewrite the following:

```
#3. 
http://www.mydomain/funfolder/folder2/sheet to
http://www.mydomain/funfolder/fakefolder3/sheet
```

when I write:

```
#4.
RewriteRule ^funfolder/folder2/sheet$ /funfolder/fakefolder3/sheet?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

or

```
#5.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /funfolder/folder2/
RewriteRule ^funfolder/folder2/(.*) /funfolder/fakefolder3/$1 [L,R=301]
```

it is not working.  I do not see the content i want to see.

If I

```
#6.
Redirect 301 /funfolder/folder2  http://www.mydomain/funfolder/fakefolder3
```

The redirect works but not the content.

I don't know if it helps but funfolder isn't a real folder.  Neither are folder2 or fakefolder3.  The CMS (joomla), however, generates the folder2 and funfolder.  but I want to add the fakefolder3.

I also though of moving the order of the above rules since there are other rewrite rules.  But, it did not produce any difference.

what I don't understand, is why the #1 works and the #2 doesn't.  I'm thinking that if I can understand the reason, it might also give me the answer to how to do #3. with a slithly altered #4 or altered a #5

Then I can always add a #6 if I need to.

this make any sence?  anyone know why I can't get #2 to work (and thus, my real problem), how to get #3 to work trough #4 or #5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the power of `RedirectMatch`! So your redirect will be:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /funfolder/folder2/(.*) /funfolder/fakefolder3/$1
```

Comment: I tried it and it did redirect but it didn't show the content.  @itoctopus However, I will try to read up and play around with RedirectMatch.  I did not know about this. Thanks!!

Comment: If it didn't show the content then this means that you are missing the menu item (or the correct menu structure) on your Joomla website.

Answer (score 0):

I have part of an answer to my question, although it is not totally what I intended.  I wanted an answer with htaccess, which I did not find, but I found a solution within the CMS.

I created an invisible menu pointing to the working link and then I used that new invisible menu item and pointed a new visible menu item on it.  That had the results I wanted/needed.  The new visible link (alias) was made to fit the need.

I'm still looking for a solution with pure htaccess..... but till I find it, at least I have somehting that works.